# Calculating Sum - Datagridview's CellFormating event too slow performance

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am using dataGridView1_CellFormatting for making sum to each my column. But this makes my datagridview very slow on scrolling. Εspecially when i have big amount of data.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {

        Decimal sum = 0, sum2 = 0, sum3 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < CustomersGrid.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {

                sum += Convert.ToDecimal(CustomersGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value);
                sum2 += Convert.ToDecimal(CustomersGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value);
                sum3 += Convert.ToDecimal(CustomersGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Value);
        }

        Quantitytxt.Text = sum2.ToString() + "   ";
        Sumtxt.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", sum).Replace(",", ".") + "€" + "   ";
        DiscountSumtxt.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", sum3).Replace(",", ".") + "€" + "   ";

    }
```

Is there any more effective way for this? Example to make my sum only when i will get this cell? Or if there is any other event or method for this? Ι also tried this.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {

        Decimal sum = 0, sum2 = 0, sum3 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < CustomersGrid.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 7 || e.ColumnIndex == 6 || e.ColumnIndex == 8)
            {
                sum += Convert.ToDecimal(CustomersGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value);
                sum2 += Convert.ToDecimal(CustomersGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value);
                sum3 += Convert.ToDecimal(CustomersGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Value);
            }
        }
        Quantitytxt.Text = sum2.ToString() + "   ";
        Sumtxt.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", sum).Replace(",", ".") + "€" + "   ";
        DiscountSumtxt.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", sum3).Replace(",", ".") + "€" + "   ";

    }
```

It looks little better performance, but it still is slow when i am scrolling my datagridview.

Comment: You can `Sum` the values on your `DataSource` (*using something similar to **Linq** *) and then provide it to the `DataGridView`. Instead of doing on every `cell`.

Comment: `CellFormatting` is raised for each cell. You're parsing the whole recordset each time a Cell content needs to be formatted. Not even modified. You could perform the calculation when the DataSource has filled the DGV and then when Rows are added/removed or the content of a *sensible* Cell is changed. The initial count could also be performed by the SQL. Maybe, also after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already mentioned in the [documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks):

> The CellFormatting event occurs every time each cell is painted, so
>   you should avoid lengthy processing when handling this event. This
>   event also occurs when the cell FormattedValue is retrieved or its
>   GetFormattedValue method is called.

Handling `CellFormatting` for all cells is too much for calculating `Sum`.

If you are using a `DataSource` like `DataTable` which raises `ListChanged` event, to calculate the `Sum`, you can rely on `ListChanged` event.

As another option, you can rely on `RowsAdded`, `RowsRemoved` and `CellValueChanged` event of `DataGridView` to calculate the `Sum`.

**Example - DataTable - Sum of a Column**

`DataTable` raises `ListChange` event. You can subscribe to the event for updating the text box:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Define data table
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(int));

    // Fill data
    dt.Rows.Add("Product 1", 100);
    dt.Rows.Add("Product 2", 200);

    // Set data source of data grid view
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    // Automatically update text box, by SUM of price
    textBox1.Text = $"{dt.Compute("SUM(Price)", ""):F2}";
    dt.DefaultView.ListChanged += (obj, args) =>
        textBox1.Text = $"{dt.Compute("SUM(Price)", ""):F2}";
}
```

**Example - List<T> - Sum of a Property**

`List<T>` doesn't raise `ListChanged` event. You can use `BindingSource` as data source and handle `ListChanged` event of `BindingSource` instead:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Define list
    var list = new List<Product>();

    // Fill data
    list.Add(new Product { Name = "Product 1", Price = 100 });
    list.Add(new Product { Name = "Product 2", Price = 200 });

    // Set data source of data grid view
    var bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = list;
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;

    // Automatically update text box, by SUM of price
    textBox1.Text = $"{list.Sum(x => x.Price):F2}";
    bs.ListChanged += (obj, args) =>
        textBox1.Text = $"{list.Sum(x => x.Price):F2}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I solved problem with lagging `DataGridView` while scrolling.
There is property `DoubleBuffered` for `DataGridView` in `.NET` but for some unknown reasons it is hidden.
You can enable it by `Reflexion` writing extension method for `DataGridView`.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void DoubleBuffered(this DataGridView dgv, bool setting)
    {
        Type dgvType = dgv.GetType();
        PropertyInfo pi = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, null);
    }
}
```

Put this code somewhere in your project and after initialization of your form, set property `DoubleBuffered` to `true`:

```
dataGridView1.DoubleBuffered(true);
```

It helped me with a performance of `DataGridView` a lot. Hope, it can help you.

Comment: This *could* help if you have a timer that refreshes the content of  a DGV every `N` seconds (UI related). Not with parsing/calculating values.