# How to sum datagridview selected cell CORRECTLY

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

it's working but not correctly 
... if selecting from up to down it's sum correct somewhere, but Down to up select doesnt summing

```
private void SalesGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float sumNumbers = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SalesGridView.SelectedCells.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!SalesGridView.SelectedCells.Contains(SalesGridView.Rows[i].Cells["TotalBillColumn"]))
        {
            float nextNumber = 0;


            if (float.TryParse(SalesGridView.SelectedCells[i].FormattedValue.ToString(), out nextNumber))
                sumNumbers += nextNumber;


           label1.Text = "selected value " + sumNumbers;
            label2.Text = "nr selected cells " + SalesGridView.SelectedCells.Count.ToString();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use `Compute` here as with [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3779835/7948962)? It seems like this approach is the "scenic route". I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "up to down" and "down to up" but if you are getting different values based on the order of your records then I would guess you're not summing the correct rows.

Comment: I suppose this question is about winforms?

Comment: yes winforms datagridview

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54783443/3110834

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
private void SalesGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float sumNumbers = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SalesGridView.SelectedCells.Count; i++)
    {
        var selectedCell = SalesGridView.SelectedCells[i];
        if (selectedCell.ColumnIndex == SalesGridView.Columns["TotalBillColumn"].Index)
        {
            float nextNumber = 0;

            if (float.TryParse(selectedCell.FormattedValue.ToString(), out nextNumber))
                sumNumbers += nextNumber;
        }
    }

    label1.Text = "selected value " + sumNumbers;
    label2.Text = "nr selected cells " + SalesGridView.SelectedCells.Count.ToString();
}
```

Sorry, for the late explanation, when I wrote that answer didn't have time to elaborate what your actual problem is and only gave you a solution that should work.

Your problem can be located at that line:

```
if (!SalesGridView.SelectedCells.Contains(SalesGridView.Rows[i].Cells["TotalBillColumn"]))
```

To be precise the following statment will give you wrong results:

```
SalesGridView.Rows[i]
```

You will receive unwanted results, because `i` doesn't fit your requirement of an index of your `Rows`, so lets look at what you wrote in your `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < SalesGridView.SelectedCells.Count; i++)
```

Your `for` loop tries to enumerate the `SelectedCells` of your `SalesGridView`.

So lets assume you select 5 cells, than your for loop with enumerate from `0` to exclusive `5`, so i will be `0, 1, 2, 3 or 4`.

Now lets check again with the problematic statement I mentioned earlier:

```
SalesGridView.Rows[i]
```

Does the `SelectedCell` with for example `i = 0` correspone with `Rows[0]` no it doesn't have to.

Your `SelectedCells` could be of any row and your `for` loop will always enumerate from `0` to `SelectedCells.Count` but your statementment of `SalesGridView.Rows[i]` will always try to get the `Row` with the given index of `i`.

So, for example:

1. You select `2` cells in row `6` and `7`.
2. `SelectedCells.Count` will have `2`
3. You enumerate `SelectedCells` beginning from `0` to exclusive `2`, so `i` will be `0` or `1`
4. Inside your loop you try to access the row with `i`, by calling `SalesGridView.Rows[i]`
5. as mentioned in point `3.` `i` will only be `0` or `1`, but I selected `2` cells of the rows `6` and `7`

Comment: throws ex Property or indexer 'DataGridViewCell.ColumnIndex' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only...........but it isnt set to read only.

Comment: Sorry, had a typo only wrote `=` instead of `==`

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double result = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewCell  cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
    {
        result = result + double.Parse(cell.Value.ToString());
    }
    label2.Text = result.ToString();

}
```

and with TryParse if you want to go on the safe side:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double result = 0;
    double nextNumber = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewCell  cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
    {
        if (double.TryParse(cell.Value.ToString(), out result)) 
        {
            nextNumber += result;
            label2.Text = nextNumber.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```